# Unable to automatically step into the server

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, wcf-ria-services

I need to debug WPF Client with RIA Services. In VS 2010 it was working fine and now I am under VS 2012 and I an facing this error.

Any clue how to return to debugging?

[image]

I have already checked web.config and it has  `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try right click on devenv.exe and select Troubleshoot compatibility? And always execute VS with administrator permission.